# Didn't get the required output

Tags: java

i don't understand why i am getting the output for next element when the program is terminated by the loop condition. if i input 3 the program terminates asking for the 3rd value but didn't input anything. what's the problem

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("number of word you want to input");
    int NumberOfWord = in.nextInt();
   System.out.println("input the words-->");
    for (int i = 0; i <= NumberOfWord; i++) {
        userInput[i] = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter your "+(i+1)+"th word");
```

Comment: `nextInt()` finishes just after the entered number, and needs another `nextLine()` to finish the rest of the line(, which may be empty)...

Comment: Declare userInput appropriately. It is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the `in.nextInt()` it only reads the integer value from the input stream. But it won't read the newline character that comes after that.

What you can do is use a dummy `in.nextLine()` before calling the `nextLine()` method in your loop which is used to read the newline character that comes after the integer value.

```
int NumberOfWord = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();
System.out.println("input the words-->");
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfWord; i++) {
   userInput[i] = in.nextLine();
   System.out.println("enter your " + (i + 1) + "th word");
}
```

Another solution is to use the `nextLine()` method itself to read the integer value also. The `nextLine()` method reads an entire line from the stream with the newline character as the termination point(includes the newline character also). So it takes care of the issue that was happening while using the `nextInt()`

```
int NumberOfWord = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
System.out.println("input the words-->");
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfWord; i++) {
    userInput[i] = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("enter your " + (i + 1) + "th word");
}
```

Also in your loop condition you where using `<=` which will ask for one more value as your loop is starting from `0`

Comment: what i want is...not to print the last output where it ask for another input

Comment: @RafiUddin edited the ans and fixed the issue.

Comment: thanks man.... but what the in.nextLine(); did

Comment: @RafiUddin I have added what it does in the begnning of the answer